# cv2 rotate changes image file size

Tags: python, opencv, image-rotation

When I rotate an image with OpenCV, everything seems to be working. Here is my code:

```
import cv2

np_arr = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
print(np_arr.shape)
rotated_img = cv2.rotate(np_arr, cv2.cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
print(rotated_img.shape)
```

Result:

```
(1144, 1037, 3) # before rotation
(1037, 1144, 3) # after rotation
```

But, when I save rotated image, new image size is different:

```
cv2.imwrite('2.jpg', rotated_img)
```

Result:

```
# 131.0kb --> old image size
# 216.9kb --> rotated image size
```

**Why ???**

Comment: Have you tried doing the same to a bmp image? Maybe this is image file type related issue:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/84292/if-an-image-is-rotated-losslessly-why-does-the-file-size-change

Comment: It is likely that the write is made with a different compression ratio. Have a try with `2.jpg`. In any case, don't expect exactly the same size.

Comment: JPEG uses [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). `np_arr = cv2.imread("1.jpg")` decodes the compressed image into "raw" RGB format. `cv2.imwrite('2.jpg', rotated_img)` re-encodes the RGB image without knowing that the source was JPEG. The encoding process is lossy - we loose quality (OpenCV uses lower compression ratio for "loosing less quality", so the file is larger). It's possible to rotate a JPEG image without loosing quality using [jpegtran](https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran) for example. But... the image resolution must be a multiple of 16 in each axis.

Comment: If your image is rectangular as opposed to square and you rotate 90 or 270 degrees, then the width and height values are interchanged because the image goes from landscape to portrait or vice-versa.